# Wordpress get_post_meta function.php

Tags: wordpress

```
function getcity(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $post; 
    if($_POST['state'])
    {
        $id=$_POST['state'];

        $district = get_post_meta($post->ID , district, true);
        var_dump($district);
        $result=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM districts WHERE state_id='$id'");

        foreach($result as $row) {
            $city_name   = $row->district_name;
            $city_id     = $row->district_id;
            // echo '<option value="'.$city_id.'">'.$city_name.'</option>';
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $city_id; ?>" <?php if($district == $city_id){ echo
                'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $city_name; ?></option>
            <?php

        }
    }
}
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getcity", "getcity");
add_action("wp_ajax_getcity", "getcity");
```

This is my function in function.php file where I want to get post_id of current post and I want to show selected value in dropdown..

Comment: Use "get_the_ID()" to get the current post id outside the loop.

Comment: check my answer on the other question hope it will help

Comment: @dwhite.me can you explain how it can be done

Comment: Start with **$district = get_post_meta(get_the_ID() , district, true);** and let me know if there's any change. **$post->ID** only (should) works in the loop or if you use **global $post** (not reccommended).

Comment: no, it's not working...

Comment: Have you added ajaxurl to your frontend?

Comment: no..I havent added ajaxurl..